# Determining last character of letter

Tags: c++, string, c++17

thanks for helping me out
this code was very helpful too

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::array<int,'Z'-'A'+1> counters{0}; // 26 counters
    std::string s;               
    std::stringstream fileIn ("Hello world");  // I use a string instead of a file for demo purpose     
    while (fileIn>>s)
    {
        if (s.empty()) continue;
        char c = toupper(s.back());
        if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
            counters[c-'A']++;
    }
    for (char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++)
    {
        std::cout << "There are "<< counters[c-'A'] <<" words that end with " << c << std::endl;
        // std::cout << std::format("There are {} words that end with {}", counters[c-'A'], c) << std::endl; // C++20
    }    
}
```

thanks for the help every1, i learned alot from ur help

Comment: Well, inspect your code line by line with your debugger, check the variable values, and find where your logic fails.

Comment: Holy cow. Please use an array of 26 counters instead of 26 different variables. How much patience do you have? Didn't you feel stupid typing the same thing over and over again?

Comment: @ThomasWeller isn't that what copy/paste was invented for?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: whenever you press Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in an IDE, there's probably a better way to implement it.

Comment: Hint: -1 doesn't deliver the last character.  C++ is not Python.

Comment: The minus one index is not a thing in C++ `s[-1]`. (this is not python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. Using 26 separate counters vs. an array obscures many things (bugs).
2. You only loop for `A`, so all other counters will be 0.
3. Doing `s[-1]` causes an exception

---

Here is some refactored code. Please excuse the use of the `printf`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int
main(void)
{
    int Ctr[26] = { 0 };
    string inputFileName;               // Declare variables
    string s;                           // for storage
    ifstream fileIn;                    // and file handling

    cin >> inputFileName;
    fileIn.open(inputFileName.data());
    assert(fileIn.is_open());

    while (fileIn >> s) {
#if 0
        char chr = s[-1];
#else
        size_t len = s.length();
        char chr = s[len - 1];
#endif

        if (isalpha(chr)) {
            chr = tolower(chr);
            Ctr[chr - 'a'] += 1;
        }
    }

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < 26;  ++idx) {
        int cnt = Ctr[idx];
        if (cnt) {
            int chr = idx + 'a';
#if 0
            cout << "\nThere are " << cnt <<
                " words that end with " << tolower(chr) << " or "
                << toupper(chr) << endl;
#else
            printf("There are %d words that end with %c or %c\n",
                cnt,tolower(chr),toupper(chr));
#endif
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is some test input I used:

```
Able Baker esac delta
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
There are 1 words that end with a or A
There are 1 words that end with c or C
There are 1 words that end with e or E
There are 1 words that end with r or R
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Looks awesome, easy to understand compared to mine :), how can I print the letters that have 0 words were found as well? –
> Jake Adams

A few options:

1. The TL;DR: Change `if (cnt) {` into `if (1) {`
2. Just remove the `if (cnt) {` and its corresponding `}` [and reindent the remaining code].
3. Add a command line option (e.g. `-a`).

Here's a version that uses a command line option:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int opt_a;                              // 1=print all counts

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int Ctr[26] = { 0 };
    string inputFileName;               // Declare variables
    string s;                           // for storage
    ifstream fileIn;                    // and file handling

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    // decode command line options
    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'a':  // show all counts [even those that are zero]
            opt_a = ! opt_a;
            break;
        }
    }

    cin >> inputFileName;
    fileIn.open(inputFileName.data());
    assert(fileIn.is_open());

    while (fileIn >> s) {
        size_t len = s.length();
        char chr = s[len - 1];

        if (isalpha(chr)) {
            chr = tolower(chr);
            Ctr[chr - 'a'] += 1;
        }
    }

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < 26;  ++idx) {
        int cnt = Ctr[idx];

        if (cnt || opt_a) {
            int chr = idx + 'a';
            printf("There are %d words that end with %c or %c\n",
                cnt,tolower(chr),toupper(chr));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output using `./myprogram -a`:

```
There are 1 words that end with a or A
There are 0 words that end with b or B
There are 1 words that end with c or C
There are 0 words that end with d or D
There are 1 words that end with e or E
There are 0 words that end with f or F
There are 0 words that end with g or G
There are 0 words that end with h or H
There are 0 words that end with i or I
There are 0 words that end with j or J
There are 0 words that end with k or K
There are 0 words that end with l or L
There are 0 words that end with m or M
There are 0 words that end with n or N
There are 0 words that end with o or O
There are 0 words that end with p or P
There are 0 words that end with q or Q
There are 1 words that end with r or R
There are 0 words that end with s or S
There are 0 words that end with t or T
There are 0 words that end with u or U
There are 0 words that end with v or V
There are 0 words that end with w or W
There are 0 words that end with x or X
There are 0 words that end with y or Y
There are 0 words that end with z or Z
```

Comment: Looks awesome, easy to understand compared to mine :), how can I print the letters that have 0 words were found as well?

Comment: @JakeAdams I've added an update to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the `back()` function for `std::string`:

You can use it like this:

```
std::string str ("Testing");
cout << str.back()
```

The output will be: `g`

Comment: Test for empty before using `back()`

Comment: whats the easiest way to fix my code without changing much?

Comment: @JakeAdams You may also want to look at [std::to_lower()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower)

Comment: @JakeAdams -- *whats the easiest way to fix my code without changing much?* -- To be honest, the best way is to see someone implement a solution, and you learn from it.  Your attempt at a solution is not really conducive to having a couple of things change here or there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion of almost a complete rewrite of your code. Yet, it still considers ASCII input. The term "character" or "letter" might certainly be interpreted differently in languages like Japanese or Chinese. You don't just have 26 letters there.

Please look at this code, understand how much shorter it is than the code you posted and then dive into the things you don't understand (google it).

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::array<int,'Z'-'A'+1> counters{0}; // 26 counters
    std::string s;               
    std::stringstream fileIn ("Hello world");  // I use a string instead of a file for demo purpose     
    while (fileIn>>s)
    {
        if (s.empty()) continue;
        char c = toupper(s.back());
        if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
            counters[c-'A']++;
    }
    for (char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++)
    {
        std::cout << "There are "<< counters[c-'A'] <<" words that end with " << c << std::endl;
        // std::cout << std::format("There are {} words that end with {}", counters[c-'A'], c) << std::endl; // C++20
    }    
}
```

Comment: Also the assumption is that this is run under an ASCII system.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: as in the original question, or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, but just to warn anyone other than the OP looking at the answer and they happen to be using a non-ASCII system.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: okay. I added this to the answer. Thanks.